# Getting unexpected value of LI element if value is of 10 digits

Tags: javascript, html

If I assign a value of length greater than 9 (eg: 9878877887) then some random number is assigned as the value of the `<li>`.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');
const outputSpan = document.getElementById('output');

list.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.value = 9868458424;
  outputSpan.innerText = event.target.value;
});
```

```css
#list {
  list-style: none;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li id="list">Click me</li>
</ol>

<p>Expected value: 9868458425</p>

Assigned value: <span id="output"></span>
```

Here is a demo of the issue I'm facing [demo](https://codepen.io/mpratap-dev/pen/YzNedpz?editors=0010).

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. The relevant code belongs directly into your question, in text form and properly formatted, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Comment: You are messing this up with `event.target.value = "9868458424";` here. The event target is your LI element, and the `value` of those refers to the ordinal value of the list item, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li#attributes Why are you trying to _set_ that in the first place?

Comment: `li` elements **must** reside inside a `ul` or `ol` parent.

Comment: I like how an interesting question with clearly reproducible problem is being downvoted.
I don't see any explanation why the "ordinal value" is being modified

Comment: @TJ The reproducer is based on invalid HTML, so anything we observe here has no substance to it.

Comment: @connexo Maybe someone out there knows exactly what's happening. Maybe it's a browser bug. This is how things get  found out and documented. I see no reason to downvote an interesting case just because OP has invalid HTML. I am allowed to ask a question about invalid HTML

Comment: *Maybe it's a browser bug.* We won't be able to tell as long as the HTML is invalid. Unspecified behaviour cannot be a bug in the first place. And btw, I haven't downvoted.

Comment: @TJ I don't think it's a bug per se but rather unexpected behavior of mutating something that probably should be enumerable. Also `typeof value` of an `<li>` is `"number"` I discovered

Answer (score 2):

So bad trick:

the value property of elements of type LI is obviously only of numeric type (automatically converted to numeric)  on 32 bits only
the value of `9868458425` is `24c34b9b9` in hexadedimal
which gives truncated on 32 bits `4c34b9b9` or the value `1278523833`

Change your `LI` tag to a `DIV` and everything will be in order, and you will at least have valid HTML

Answer (score 1):

Unlike form controls the  `value` of an `<li>` must be an integer and it is used as the ordinal number to display in an `<ol>`.

If you click on list below will see the `typeof` the values are Number

Mutating `event.target.value` in an event listener, especially with a string,  makes no sense and you should treat that as readOnly.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ol')

list.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify([typeof e.target.value, e.target.value]) )
});

const item  = document.createElement('li');
item.value=110;
item.textContent ='Appended with value'
list.appendChild(item)

const item2  = document.createElement('li');
item2.textContent ='Appended No value'
list.appendChild(item2)
```

```html
<ol> 
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li value="37">Three</li>
  <li value="95">Four</li>
</ol>
```